# How do I have `w` command output 10 characters for USER?

Tags: users

`w` command shows who is logged on and what they are doing which outputs only first 8 characters at most by default for USER. How do I let it output more characters, say 10?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man w`:

```
ENVIRONMENT
       PROCPS_USERLEN
              Override  the default width of the username column.  Defaults to
              8.

       PROCPS_FROMLEN
              Override the default width of the from column.  Defaults to 16.
```

so for example

```
PROCPS_USERLEN=10 w
```

You can of course `export PROCPS_USERLEN=10` in your shell's initialization file to make it persistent.